# how to assign value to an array of nodes in OMNETPP.INI

Tags: omnet++, inet

There are 10 nodes in the network and I wanted to assign Node [0] to Node [4] with ValueA= 10, the rest with Value=90 in OMNETPP.INI. The only silly way I could think of to assign the value as follows:

```
**.*Node[0].ValueA= "10"
**.*Node[1].ValueA= "10"
......
......
**.*Node[5].ValueA= "90"
**.*Node[6].ValueA= "90"
.......
.......
```

I'm thinking to assign the value with a more efficient way with FOR loop but I don't think it is possible in the OMNETPP.INI. 
Can anyone help to enlighten me how to achieve this? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various options and ways to do this are available.
You could for example use:

```
**.Node[0..4].ValueA = "10"
**.Node[5..9].ValueA = "90"
```

Check the [OMNET Simulation manual -> Chapter Wildcard](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:wildcards) patterns for additional information.